# Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:' - pipe:: Invalid argument

Tags: facebook, ffmpeg, live-streaming

I'm working on a project to potentially simplify some of the process to send video to something like Facebook Live.

Right now I'm using [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites) example with a FB Live API RTMP endpoint (neither of these are production or real development commands - by using this example I think I can figure out the limitations of what I'm doing in others):

```
-i - -map 0 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -muxrate 1000k -bufsize 2000k -g 50 -f tee "rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/10104590177564330?ds=1&s_e=4&s_l=1&a=ATgko8JiGpXC0WGf"
```

Here's the original example:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input -map 0 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -bufsize 2000k -g 50 -f tee \ "[f=flv:onfail=ignore]rtmp://facebook|[f=flv:onfail=ignore]r‌​tmp://youtube|local_‌​file.mkv"
```

However, despite using that example I'm getting:

`[NULL @ 0xffd840] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:'

pipe:: Invalid argument`

I understand that sometimes this error arises due to spacing issues or incorrect syntax. I've looked around to try to resolve this problem and using many combinations does not change the result.

Thanks!

Edit - Log added:

```
 configuration: --cc=emcc --prefix=/Users/bgrinstead/Sites/videoconverter.js/build/ffmpeg/../dist --extra-cflags='-I/Users/bgrinstead/Sites/videoconverter.js/build/ffmpeg/../dist/include -v' --enable-cross-compile --target-os=none --arch=x86_32 --cpu=generic --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-asm --disable-doc --disable-devices --disable-pthreads --disable-w32threads --disable-network --disable-hwaccels --disable-parsers --disable-bsfs --disable-debug --disable-protocols --disable-indevs --disable-outdevs --enable-protocol=file --enable-libvpx --enable-gpl --extra-libs='/Users/bgrinstead/Sites/videoconverter.js/build/ffmpeg/../dist/lib/libx264.a /Users/bgrinstead/Sites/videoconverter.js/build/ffmpeg/../dist/lib/libvpx.a'
```

It specifically fails here:

```
.../
libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
```

Comment: Which example is it? The only one that seems to match, you've omitted some important things. Run your command with `-report` and share the log.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help. I'm using a simplified version of: $ ffmpeg -i input -map 0 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -bufsize 2000k -g 50 -f tee \
"[f=flv:onfail=ignore]rtmp://facebook|[f=flv:onfail=ignore]rtmp://youtube|local_file.mkv"

Comment: The command I'm using doesn't require "FFMPEG" be used at the start as we're using a clientside emscripten build

Comment: Unless that script is using FFmpeg API, it's just a front-end for the CLI binary. So, still need to see the command being executed. Add `-report`, which will generate a textfile in PWD which contains both the command as ffmpeg sees it and the log as well.

Comment: Hi, this project got canned but my apologies for the delay in replying. Appreciate the help. This is a videorecorder.js port of FFMPEG - https://bgrins.github.io/videoconverter.js/

Comment: So, like I said it uses the actual FFMPEG API and the examples I gave are syntactically valid inputs. My opinion is that it's a problem with the library (dates back to 2014 I think).

Comment: This approach seems to be a natural choice for a lot of people only for them to be stymied. I was hoping that the maturation of the WebRTC API would help facilitate a direct browser to RTMP server option saving cost dramatically. WebRTC is H264 and Opus while RTMP is H264 and AAC requiring merely audio to be transcoded.

Comment: Normally, one has their users stream to one or more servers on the backend before broadcasted the output to another server or back to the users. The hosting costs are fairly pricey if you have reached scale. Ultimately given one stream to your backend you might be seeing 2-4X that many streams in hosting costs.